# Session is timing out on the drop down selected index change

Tags: asp.net

Session is timing out on the drop down selected index change

20 minutes ago | LINK

Hello Everyone,

I am facing a weird problem here. I have a report page on which i am using a drop down list which has different years. When user select the year=2009, i am displaying report for 2009 data. The code is given below. The website is live on our web server now. The page access havy data, so sometime it takes one minute or more to load the report for selected year and when that is the case my session expires and user is getting redirected to the default page. But the same thing works fine in the solution in my machine and in one of our local server. It is just not working on our live server. Please help me by posting the solutions if you know any.

I have also placed this line in my web.config but it is not helping:

Code:

```
protected void ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            Session["IsDetailedReportLoaded"] = false;
            Session["IsScoreCardLoaded"] = false;
            Session["IsChartLoaded"] = false;
            Session["IsReportLoaded"] = false;

            string strYear = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
            LoadReport(Convert.ToInt16(strYear));
            lblYear.Text = strYear;
            lblAsOf.Text = strYear;           
            lblYear.Text = ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
            lblAsOf.Text = ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
            ddlYearDetail.SelectedValue = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
            ddlYearScorecard.SelectedValue = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
            ddlYearGraph.SelectedValue = ddlYear.SelectedValue;

            mpeLoading.Hide();
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Thanks,

Satish k.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem could be that the web server is running out of memory and forcing the app pool to recycle. This would flush the InProc Session memory. You could try using Sql Session State instead and see if that resolves the problem. Try monitoring the web server processes and see if they're recycling quickly.

Comment: what I need to check to make sure my server is flushing the memory?

Comment: Also, What i need to change in my web.config to use sql session state?

Comment: @Corgalore: +1 for a good thought. Managing Session State in SQL might be overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a

```
if(Session.IsNew)
```

check in your code and redirect/stop code execution appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the Performance tab in IIS to see whether a bandwidth threshold is set.

1. Right click on website in IIS
2. Performance tab
3. Check "Bandwidth throttling" limit

If a treshold is set you might be hitting the maximum bandwidth (KB per second) limit. Either disable bandwidth throttling, or increase the limit.

Comment: it is disabled already. I also tried to increase the bandwidth but it didn't help.